# How to run a pytest test function on all data files in a folder

Tags: python, pandas, pytest

I have a set of functions that I am attempting to write pytest unit tests for. The function I am trying to write a test for looks like so:

```
def IndexLevel(df: pd.DataFrame, index_row: str, start_col: str, end_col: str) -> pd.DataFrame:

    # Editing df
    return df_index
```

And the pytest function looks like so (`df_format_index` is a fixture to test `df_index` shape):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "df, index_row, start_col, end_col, df_format_index",
    [(function("blah.txt"), "index level", "index level", "Equity 2", df_format_index)],
    indirect=["df_format_index"],
)
def test_IndexLevel(df: pd.DataFrame, index_row: str, start_col: str, end_col: str, df_format_index: pd.DataFrame):
    print("-----test-IndexLevel------")
    assert (IndexLevel(df: pd.DataFrame, index_row, start_col, end_col).shape == df_format_index.shape)
```

These functions work if I hard code the filename, but I would like to thoroughly test them by running the test on all data files in a folder. I have tried to use the following function, but it did not work:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    filelist = glob.glob("Data/*.txt")
    metafunc.parametrize("filename", filelist)
```

How can I run the test on all files in the data folder without editing the original function?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you could use `eval` function in python to run code inside python code dynamically.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago Thank you for your input. How would you use eval in this context though?

Comment: Put dynamic code as an string input in `eval` function. Before that generate string dynamically by for loop and joining string values in a loop and after that pass it to eval function.

Comment: From the bits of code you have posted, you are already using the indirect parametrization on a test argument `df_format_index`; you can use that on the `df` argument as well. It is hard to write a working answer though since your `IndexLevel` function looks weird: why passing `df` if you are obviously reading it from file in the function, overwriting the input? Where does `filename` come from? Is it a global variable? I would reiterate on that first, then writing a clean data-driven test will be a lot easier.

Comment: @hoefling You're right, I needed to rework the function a bit. I'll post an updated solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. Since `pytest.mark.parametrize` takes a list of tuples, I made a function that returns a list of tuples as testing parameters. Hope it helps somebody!

```
def IndexLevel(filename: str, index_row: str, start_col: str, end_col: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Editing a df from the file
    return df_index
```

```
def file_loop_index() -> list:
    filenames = []
    files = glob.glob("Data/*.txt")
    for file in files:
        filenames.append(tuple((file, "index level", "s&p500", "equity 2", df_format_index)))
    return filenames

# Testing df_index shape against the dummy dataframe
@pytest.mark.parametrize("filename, index_row, start_col, end_col, df_format_index", file_loop_index(), indirect=["df_format_index"])
def test_IndexLevel(
    filename: str,
    index_row: str,
    start_col: str,
    end_col: str,
    df_format_index: pd.DataFrame,
):
    print("-----test-IndexLevel------")
    assert (IndexLevel(filename, index_row, start_col, end_col).shape == df_format_index.shape)
```